# ¿Como puedo actualizar un datagrid desde otro formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Estoy haciendo un programa de Windows forms C#, uso un datagridview como carrito de compras, el caso es que al agregar más de un producto al datgridview, se agrega uno solo, ¿qué debo hacer para agregar más de uno correctamente? Cabe destacar que todas las ventanas se abren afuera de la otra.

En el diseño de la vista tengo la imagen de un martillo con el botón de agregar al carrito, dicho botón tiene este código:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Carrito carro = new Carrito();
    carro.Show();
    
    carro.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    
    cProducto producto = new cProducto();
    
    producto.Nombre = "Martillo de uña 7 onzas";
    producto.Tipoherramienta = "Manual de golpeo";
    producto.Precio = 95;
    
    List<cProducto> golpeo = new List<cProducto>();
    
    golpeo.Add(producto);
    
    foreach (var elemento in golpeo)
        carro.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(elemento.Nombre, elemento.Tipoherramienta, 
                    elemento.Precio);
}
```

En la segunda vista hay otro martillo diferente, hay exactamente los mismos componentes, solo cambia el nombre de la herramienta, y su precio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la clase de la ventana principal donde se encuentra el botón "Agregar al carrito", declara una lista de productos a nivel de clase que contendrá los productos agregados al carrito. Por ejemplo, agrega esta línea antes del constructor de la clase:

```
private List<cProducto> productosEnCarrito = new List<cProducto>();
```

Ahora, en el evento del botón "Agregar al carrito", simplemente agrega el producto a la lista productosEnCarrito en lugar de crear una nueva lista cada vez:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Elimina esta línea, ya que crear una nueva lista cada vez eliminará los productos anteriores.
    // List<cProducto> golpeo = new List<cProducto>();

    // Crea y agrega el producto a la lista de productos en el carrito.
    cProducto producto = new cProducto();
    producto.Nombre = "Martillo de uña 7 onzas";
    producto.Tipoherramienta = "Manual de golpeo";
    producto.Precio = 95;

    productosEnCarrito.Add(producto);
}
```

Luego, cuando se abre la ventana del carrito, puedes iterar sobre la lista productosEnCarrito para agregar todos los productos al DataGridView:

```
public class Carrito : Form {
    public void MostrarProductosEnCarrito(List<cProducto> productos) {
        foreach (var elemento in productos) {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(elemento.Nombre, elemento.Tipoherramienta, elemento.Precio);
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, desde la primera ventana (donde tienes el botón "Agregar al carrito"), cuando muestras la ventana del carrito, simplemente pasa la lista productosEnCarrito como un parámetro tal que así:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
// Supongo que tienes más codigo, por lo que lo tienes que poner aquí

    // Mostrar el carrito y pasar la lista de productos en el carrito.
    Carrito carro = new Carrito();
    carro.Show();

    carro.dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;

    // Poner esta linea al final del codigo
    carro.MostrarProductosEnCarrito(productosEnCarrito);
}
```

De esta manera, cuando agregues un producto al carrito desde la primera ventana, se mantendrá en la lista productosEnCarrito, y al abrir la ventana del carrito, todos los productos agregados se mostrarán correctamente en el DataGridView. Además, podrás seguir agregando más productos al carrito y se mostrarán todos en la segunda ventana.

Comment: aplique todo lo que dijiste, salió un inconveniente, al poner 

 public void MostrarProductosEnCarrito(List<cProducto> productos) {
        foreach (var elemento in productos) {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(elemento.Nombre, elemento.Tipoherramienta, elemento.Precio);


en la clase del carrito, marcó un error en la parte "MostrarProductosEnCarrito", el error dice:

incoherencia de accesibilidad: el tipo de parametro List<cProducto> es menos accesible que el metodo "carrito.MostrarProductosEnCarrito(List<cProducto> )


¿que se debe de hacer en ese caso?